# Why we can still use this function when it's dividing zero

Tags: calculus, functions

my teacher gave my class a question in calculus but the method he used to attempt the question was kind of odd.

Question: An aircraft at a constant 500 metres height is flying towards an observer at 80 m/s. How is the angle of elevation changing if the aircraft is overhead?

He did:
let the elevation angle be $\theta$. then we have function:
***tan $\theta$ = $500/x$*** where x is the honrizontal distance between the plane and the observer.
  Further it's just diffrentiate with respect to t and substitution (since we know $dx/dt$ is -80)

Finally we have:

$\frac{d\theta}{dt}$=$\frac{4000}{x^2}$ $\times$ $\frac{x^2}{h^2}$

My teacher told us just to cancel out the $x^2$. But isn't the function undefined when x is zero?

Thank you.

Comment: As given, yes, but if you cancel then you obtain a function continuous at $x=0$ agreeing with your given function elsewhere. This makes for a reasonable extension.

Comment: Thanks , I think I start getting it know, the original function is undefined at x=0 but the rate of angle changing is continuous at x=0. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @B.Yu The rate of change of the elevation angle is quite obviously smooth, if you picture it in physical terms. The confusion that it may *look* like it's undefined at $x=0$ is an artifact of the choice of the $\tan \theta$ function to express the angle, which has a singularity at $\pi/2$ i.e. overhead. For an exercise, try reworking the same argument using $\cos \theta$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of like cancelling the $x$'s in the equation $y = \frac{x(x+3)(2x+5)}{x}$ when you try to find the limit as x approaches 0. The function is undefined at x = 0, but the limit still exists and still makes sense. The function $y = x(x+3)(2x+5)$ matches everywhere else except x = 0, similar to your problem with the cancelling $x^2$.

Comment: Thank you! So actually the x is still undefined at x=0 but the pathological singularity still have a y value (like we pretend it's not undefined and see what value would we get.) Did I understand your explaination corretly?

Comment: Yes. It's kind of the way calculus works, right? It allows us to do things that couldn't be done in the traditional algebra no-nonsense way. Also, please check an answer you like to resolve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, these types of singularities are called *removable* singularities, if you want to sound extra cool talking about them.